# CASE function with Boolean

Tags: formula-field, boolean

I am trying to make a checkbox (boolean) formula field on a custom object, using a CASE function to set the value. I have 5 or 6 values from a picklist that I would like to set the new checkbox to true, and the rest false. It seems the CASE function only allows text output. Is there a way to do this using CASE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the CASE function in an IF function.

```
IF(
CASE( Account.Type , 
"A", "true",
"B", "true",
"C", "true", 
"false") 
= "True", TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: jus make sure to check for case-sensitivity